# What is the probability that a specific group of four students will be chosen out of 36 students?

Tags: probability

*Nine groups of four are formed from a group of 36 students. What is the probability that a particular group of four students will be chosen? Order is unimportant.*

My first approach was to calculate how many combinations there are of arranging the 36 students in groups of four.
Using $nCr = n!/((n – r)! r!)$ with $n = 36$ and $r = 4$ I calculated that there are $58905$ combinations. There is only one particular group and therefore I think there is a $1/58905$ chance of choosing that specific group. I am not sure that this is the solution though.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.

Comment: Denote the friends as A,B,C,D.  Consider the table where A is at.  How many different ways can this table be filled?

Comment: Surely you must have put in some effort by now. Please show it in the **body** of the question. OP is expected to first make an effort, and showing no effort is likely to lead to quick deletion.

Comment: I advise you to look up combination and permutations. There will be 9 groups formed from a group of 36 students. Note that if A,B,C,D are in a group, the order doesn't matter, this means you have a combination. Maybe try to edit your question with a bit more calculations and then we can help you further!

Answer (score 1):

Repeating and extending my comment:

Label the $(4)$ pertinent people as A,B,C,D and consider the table where $A$ is sitting.  There is only $(1)$ satisfactory way of filling this table.  That is, having B,C,D also sit at this table.

However, with A seated at this table, there are $\displaystyle \binom{35}{3}$ ways of filling the table.  Therefore, the probability that A,B,C,D are all seated at the same table is :

$$\frac{1}{\binom{35}{3}}.$$